# Hadoop Pig one line contain more than one record

Tags: hadoop, tuples, apache-pig

Currently, I got a data file which process line by line, most of the line contain one record I need, such as: id,name,total

But some line contain more than one record, such as such as:id1,name1,total1,id2,name2,total2

I wrote my load function, and try to return the tuple which compose of list of tuples. But I don't know how can I process data as below?

((id1,name1,total1),(id2,name2,total2))...

And another question is about loadfun, if I found  some line contain invalid value, shall  I return an empty tuple or just set the line reader to the next line?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. For the example input you output the following tuples? `(a), (b), (c), ((a),(b),(c))` And you don't know how to access the complex tuple?

Comment: Hi  jkbkot, Thank you for the comments. My input contain record, such as (id,name,total), but some line contain more than one record, such as id1,name1,total1, id2,name2,total2.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution, which is define my own load or store.
For load, define the file input.
for the store, define the output in my my put next function as below.

```
      @Override
      public void putNext(Tuple t) throws IOException {
              List<Object> all = t.getAll();
              for (Object o : all) {
                  logger.info(o.getClass());
                  Tuple tuple = (Tuple) o;
                  try {
                      recordWriter.write(null, new Text(tuple.toString()));
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }
          }
```